# strange performance issue with scala

Tags: performance, scala

I was trying out some things in scala and found the strange performance issue demonstrated by the code below.  Here inlining a function call makes it take 4 times as long to do the calculation (4 s vs 16 s).

```
package mypackage

object MyObject extends Application {
  class Complex(val real: Double, val imaginary: Double) {
    def +(operand: Complex): Complex = {
      new Complex(real + operand.real, imaginary + operand.imaginary)
    }
    def *(operand: Complex): Complex = {
      new Complex(real * operand.real - imaginary * operand.imaginary,
        real * operand.imaginary + imaginary * operand.real)
    }
    def mag2 = real * real + imaginary * imaginary
  }

  val iSize = 1250
  val jSize = 1250
  val xMin = -2.5
  val xMax = +1.5
  val yMin = -2.0
  val yMax = +2.0
  val dx = (xMax - xMin) / iSize
  val dy = (yMax - yMin) / jSize
  val steps = 50

  def iterate(c: Complex) = {
    var z = c
    var n = 0
    do {
      z = z * z + c
      n += 1
    } while (n < steps && z.mag2 < 4.0)
  }

  // Mandelbrot set using iteration in a function.
  var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  for (i <- 0 until iSize; j <- 0 until jSize) {
    val c = new Complex(xMin + i * dx, yMin + j * dy)
    iterate(c)
  }
  System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0 + " (s)")

  // Mandelbrot set using iteration.
  startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  for (i <- 0 until iSize; j <- 0 until jSize) {
    val c = new Complex(xMin + i * dx, yMin + j * dy)
    var z = c
    var n = 0
    do {
      z = z * z + c
      n += 1
    } while (n < steps && z.mag2 < 4.0)
  }
  System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0 + " (s)")
}
```

Any idea why this would happen?  Interstingly, adding "@inline" before the "iterate" function makes it take 12 s vs 4 s.

Comment: what are your scala and java versions?

Answer (score 1):

Please replace Application to App and you get 100x speedup.

Comment: The scala.Application trait is deprecated because it has some issues (http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/07/application-trait-considered-harmful.html), if using of App is not acceptable for you, please try running in the Client mode of JVM (without -server, or explicitly set -client)

Comment: you've suggested two ways of improving this programs performance - both changing `Application` to `App` and running in `-client` mode instead of `-server` make it run in half a second. But can you explain why it happens?

Comment: "HotSpot does not optimize class initializers. Because they're run only once in the life of the class, it seems like a waste (except in this case.) ... So... the best thing to do is have an explicit main() method rather than using Application." (from http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/12795)

Comment: so what happens here is that the `iterate()` method is optimized while inlined code is not? cool :)

Comment: It seems that HotSpot starts in interpreter mode and tries to compile some methods before the main() call if they are not inlined